# JQuery check the attribute element value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<li style="padding-bottom: 0px; display: none;">
<span> Content </span>
</li>
```

i want to check `display == none`

i got the solution with the below script.

```
if($(this).closest('li').attr('style') =='padding-bottom: 0px; display: none;'){
    // script
}
```

any other simple way to write.
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue you have is that you're mixing jQuery and vanilla JS methods here, with `.attr().display`. You're also trying to compare the whole `style` string against (if it worked) one CSS rule.

A better method of achieving this would be to use jQuery's `is()` method, along with the `:visible` selector. Try this:

```
if ($(this).closest('li').is(':visible')) {
  // script
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only to check if the element is hidden you can check if the display is set to none using **[css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** method. Using `.attr('style')` it will return the whole style on the element.

```
if($(this).closest('li').css('display') == 'none' ){

}
```

Working `demonstrative` example (I've put the inline style just for demonstration, but I don't recommend you to use it):

```js
$('li').each(function(i) {
  if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {
    console.log(i); // logs the indexes of the hidden elements
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li style="padding-bottom: 0px; display: none;">
  <span> Content </span>
</li>
<li style="padding-bottom: 0px; display: none;">
  <span> Content </span>
</li>
<li style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
  <span> Content </span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :visible or :hidden selectors directly:

```
if ( $('li:visible').length > 0 ) {
    // it is visible
}
```

You can use :visible or :hidden selectors with [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
if ( $('li').is(':visible') ) {
    // it is visible
}
```

Finally, you can check the specific value of 'display' with [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
if ( $('li').css('display') === 'none' ) {
    // it is hidden
}
```